# If a salary increase of $7.39\%$ has the value €$4231$, then what is the new salary?

Tags: arithmetic

> Ryan has been given a salary increase of $7.39\%$. The salary increase is for the value of €$4231$.
>
> His salary is now $x$. Solve for $x$.

My head is saying

$$\begin{align}
4231 / 7.39 &= 572 \\
572 * 100 &= 57,200
\end{align}$$

is not correct, but I am having a brainfart right now.

Can anyone help ?

Thanks.

Comment: You calculated his salary **before** the raise. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose that Ryan's initial salary is $s$. Then the value of the salary increase is $0.0739s$, so $0.0739s = 4231$, and we get $s = 57253.04$ (watch out for rounding too soon!).

We want to calculate his *final* salary, which is
$$s + 4231.$$

In other words, you forgot to add his increase. (And you also rounded off some fifty-three euros.)

Comment: This is music to my ears <3

Answer (score 0):

As someone who's been told to go into accounting, you forgot to take markup versus margin into account. The 7.39% is a markup  on the old amount (or about a 6.88% margin on the new amount) you didn't successfully find 100% of the original amount and forgot to add the markup back in you needed to find 107.39% of the original so 572*107.39 = 57200+4004+171.6+51.48 = 61427.08 but none of that matters if you don't start with the correct numbers.

Answer (score 0):

$$
y\times 7.39\%= 4,231\quad\Longrightarrow \quad y=\frac{ 4,231}{7.39\%}=\frac{ 4,231}{0.0739}\approx 57,253\\
x=y(1+7.39\%)=57,2534+4,231=61,484
$$